# getProviders() Doesn't return network provider in its list

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying to get location providers on android.. but when i am using getProviders() it only returns only passive & gps.. it doesn't include network provider! it doesn't matter if the argument was true or false! the result is always like this..
Though i declared access fine location in manifest and enabled wifi and network location from the device settings!

my code is:

```
String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(location_context);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    System.out.println(providers);
```

the result is

```
10-29 09:36:54.484: I/System.out(1698): [passive, gps]
```

why is that?

Comment: Refer this article - http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: thank you @AshishTamrakar.. it's really great article.. but it doesn't answer my question.. still network provider doesn't appear in the list